# Setting a set date with javascript

Tags: javascript

Using a countdown plugin but I think I'm setting the date and time wrong.

Code:

```
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Grab the current date
    var currentDate = new Date();
    // Set some date in the future. In this case, it's always Jan 1
    var futureDate  = new Date(2016,10,27, 10,00,00);
    // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
    var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
    // Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock
    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        countdown: true
    });
});
```

I'm attempting this:

```
var futureDate = new Date(2016,10,27, 10,00,00);
```

Which is 27th October 2016 at 10am

Coding up 52 days though so I must be doing something wrong

Comment: In JavaScript while using `Date` constructor month starts from `0`, So to set October you need to pass `10-1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which is 27th October 2016 at 10am

That's where you're going wrong. Months in JavaScript are 0-indexed (January is 0, December is 11), the 10th month is actually November.

```
var futureDate = new Date(2016,9,27,10,00,00);
```

Comment: Ahh so was almost there, good thing to know :) thanks for that.